# Run exe present in Azure blob using Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to run an exe genetated from a C# solution. This is a command line solution. I have my exe present in Blob storage. Can I use azure functions to execute exe present in blob.

Thanks.

Comment: I am running exe using azure batch. Have not tried this. Would close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we can't use blob storage like this. You might need to look into WebJobs for this kind of task.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Answer (score 2):

We need to retrieve the exe file then execute it. Take an example of v2 c# http trigger.

```
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {

        //Download file first
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("StorgeConnectionString");
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        string fileName = "Console.exe";
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        // Use this path to store file in case the Azure site is read-only
        string path = "D:\\home\\data";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        string wholePath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(wholePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        // Execute
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = wholePath;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        int exitcode = process.ExitCode;
        if (exitcode == 0)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Executed, output: {output}");
            return new OkObjectResult($"Executed, output: {output}");
        }
        else
        {
            log.LogError($"Fail to process due to: {error}");
            return new ObjectResult($"Fail to process due to: {error}")
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            };
        }

    }
```